# Не отображается версия python. Зависание в Pyscripter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Установил Python с оф сайта. Решил проверить правильно ли отображается в командной строке (cmd) версия python. Команду использовал эту "python --version". мне выдало ответ "Python" без указания версий. Пробовал переустанавливать, ставить предыдущeю версию, устанавливать в другую директорию - не помогло.
Также есть проблема беспричинного зависания в PyScripter. Зависает периодически при наборе кода, даже если только начал набирать текст может зависнуть и через 7-30 сек отвиснуть и напечатать тот текст при котором зависло. Виснет само окно, как когда приложение не отвечает, но при этом можно спокойно пользоваться другими приложениями. Также пробовал переустанавливать - не помогло.
Версии: Python 3.9.0 (пробовал ставить 3.8.6)
PyScripter 3.6.4

Comment: с какого сайта скачал питон?

Comment: c www.python.org